# is there any difference between 'a.b.a' and 'b.b.a'

Tags: python

```
class a(object):
    class b:
        a='aaa'

print a.b.a#print 'aaa'

b=a()
print b.b.a#print 'aaa'
```

Comment: -1: Poorly chosen, unclear names: two different things named 'a'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your code and then `a.b.a is b.b.a` gives the result of `True`, which indicates that they are, indeed, referring to the same object - the class variable `a` of inner class `b`.

Answer (score 5):

No.

To create instance variables, you need to explicitly prefix them with `self.`, in  the constructor method `__init__(self)`.

In your code, you're simply assigning in the class scope, and those variables can be reached both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Either ways, you are accessing: "outerclass/object.innerclass/object.member".